# Loop through an array and perform function on each result

Tags: php, loops, foreach, civicrm

I am trying to pull the `[title]` out of the following array and then perform a function with each title.

Array:

```
Array ( 
    [is_error] => 0 
    [version] => 3 
    [count] => 2
    [values] => Array ( 
        [5] => Array ( 
            [id] => 5 
            [group_id] => 1 
            [title] => 2014rootedemail 
            [visibility] => User and User Admin Only 
            [is_hidden] => 0 
            [in_date] => 2014-08-01 07:45:39 
            [in_method] => Admin
        )
        [6] => Array ( 
            [id] => 6 
            [group_id] => 2 
            [title] => Student 2014 
            [visibility] => User and User Admin Only 
            [is_hidden] => 0 
            [in_date] => 2014-08-01 08:23:22 
            [in_method] => Admin
        )
    ) 
)
```

Here is the php I am using to try and take the group title and then pass each of them through an API for an SMS service to add the create each group on the 3rd party site and then add the contact to that group.

```
foreach ($result as &$groupt){
    $group = $project->getOrCreateGroup($groupt['title']);
    $contact->addToGroup($group); 
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class plgCiviCRMBase extends JPlugin
{

    /**
     * Base Civicrm Plugin.
     *
     * @package     Civicrm
     * @subpackage  Joomla plugins
     * @since       1.6
     */

    function civicrm_post( $op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef ) 
    {

        if (($op == 'create' || $op =='edit') && $objectName == 'Individual') {

            //Telerivet API CONNECT
            require_once JPATH_SITE.'/media/civicrm/telerivet/telerivet.php';
            $API_KEY = '----';
            $PROJECT_ID = '----';
            $telerivet = new Telerivet_API($API_KEY);
            $project = $telerivet->initProjectById($PROJECT_ID);


            //Get Variables Civicrm
            $firstName = $objectRef->first_name;
            $lastName = $objectRef->last_name;
            $phone = $objectRef->phone[0]->phone;
            $displayName = $objectRef->display_name;

            //Get Groups the contact is in... Returns Above array
            $params = array( 'contact_id' => $objectRef->id,'version' => 3,);
            require_once 'api/api.php';
            $result = civicrm_api( 'group_contact','get',$params );

            // Telerivet Post New Contact to Telerivet 
            $contact = $project->getOrCreateContact(array(
                'name' => $displayName, 
                'phone_number' => $phone, 
                'vars' => array('first' => $firstName, 'last' => $lastName)
            ));


            // Add Contact to Telerivet Groups
            //? Now how do I get each of the groups and then add the contact below for each group. for the contact?

            foreach ($result as &$groupt){
                $group = $project->getOrCreateGroup($groupt['title']);
                $contact->addToGroup($group); 
            }

            //print_r($groupt);
            //exit();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question??

Comment: What is the problem? What is not working? is there an error? Nobody will read all this code to find it out...

Comment: I think you just have to change `foreach ($result` to `foreach ($result['values']`

Answer (score 1):

[`As Charlotte Dunois pointed out in the comments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109760/loop-through-an-array-and-perform-function-on-each-result#comment39076554_25109760)

---

You need to loop through your `values` array. Right now your array looks like this:

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'is_error' => 0,
        'version' => 3,
        'count' => 2,
        'values' => array(
            '5' => array(
                'id' => 5,
                'group_id' => 1,
                'title' => '2014rootedemail',
                'visibility' => 'User and User Admin Only',
                'is_hidden' => 0,
                'in_date' => '2014-08-01 07:45:39',
                'in_method' => 'Admin',
            ),
            '6' => array(
                'id' => 6,
                'group_id' => 2,
                'title' => 'Student 2014',
                'visibility' => 'User and User Admin Only',
                'is_hidden' => 0,
                'in_date' => '2014-08-01 08:23:22 ',
                'in_method' => 'Admin',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

All you have to do is get to that `values` array and you'll be laughing. Simple enough with a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($a as $i => $item) {
    foreach ($item['values'] as $i) {
        $group = $project->getOrCreateGroup($groupt['title']);
        $contact->addToGroup($group);
    }
}
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/175034)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$array` is your whole containing array:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){

foreach($array[$i] as $key => $value){

  if($key == 'title'){
                $group = $project->getOrCreateGroup($value);
                $contact->addToGroup($group); 
   }

 }

}
```

If this doesn't help you, please narrow down your request.

Good Luck

Comment: There is no need to loop through the whole array. And you should've noticed that the keys in $array aren't numeric.